# BitMinter gpu mining error

Tags: error, gpu-mining, miner-configuration

I have recently gotten BitMinter on Linux, and was hoping to try GPU mining. However, as soon as BitMinter starts, it gives the following messages:

```
BitMinter Client v1.6.1 started  
No OpenCl-compatible GPUs detected  
Probing all ports for external devices  
Probe failed: No serial ports found  
No external devices detected.
```

If I then click the play button to run, it tells me:

```
Error: null
scala.runtime.NonLocalReturnControl$mcV$sp
```

As well, the engine start button is not showing now, however the previous issues existed before this

Answer (score 2):

You have no ASICs and no OpenCL-compatible GPU. Note that noone mines on GPU anymore anyway, it's completely useless.

Buy an ASIC miner, 1 TH/s (1000 GH/s) or faster. It will be a stand-alone machine, and you don't need to use your PC at all.

Answer (score -1):

It's also possible that he started Bitminter from an RDP-Session, there comes the same error.